# Paging in each JPA provider for multiple databases

Tags: jpa

We have many JPA provider such as : OpenJPA, Hibernate, Toplink, EclipseLink... With Hibernate it uses Dialect to implement pagination data. How other providers implement this paging feature for multiple databases if not using Dialect as Hibernate?

Comment: What paging feature? you mean maxResults and firstResult in JPQL?

Comment: Yes, it's maxResults and firstResult in JPA API. How JPA provider (exclude Hibernate) know they're working with what database to generate properly paging sql?

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus JPA implements paging using features of the datastore where available ... HSQL, Derby, Postgresql etc have LIMIT/OFFSET keywords. Oracle, DB2, MSSQL have ROWCURSOR-style keywords.

Hibernate does the exact same thing AFAIK